# How can I serialise and reuse my Model in an external JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, json, serialization, model-view-controller, model

Am trying to pass my model from `.cshtml` to an external `.js` file. Read online and found that this method `@Json.Serialize(Model)` seems to be the one to use, but am confused as to how I can use the new model in the `.js` file.

In the example below am just using the `Model.Name` attribute but I would like to use all of the other attributes too.

Also, is there a way to get IntelliSense on the Model from the Javascript file?

MODEL .cs

```
public class TSPMap
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<TSPCity> Cities { get; set; }
    }
```

VIEW Code .cshtml

```
  <!-- Prepare Data for Java Script Files -->
    <script>
        var JSModel = @Json.Serialize(Model);
    </script>
```

JAVASCRIPT .js file (EDITED)

```
function JSCanvas_functionAlert() {
    console.log(JSModel);
    console.log("The country is: %s", JSModel.Name);
  }
```

CONSOLE RESULTS (EDITED)

> {id: 1978, name: "France", cities: Array(3)}
>   The country is: undefined

Comment: You are doing it right you can access any property of your TSPMap class using JSModel variable in JavaScript. You can use console.log(JSModel) to check what you are receiving at client side

Comment: Thx @ZakiMohammed, I edited the post. The first Log returns the right content in the console, my Model is there. How can I use it to access a specific variable? The intellisense on JS side does not give me the content from it.

Comment: It is very simple write JSModel.name to access name to access id write JSModel.id and to access your cities array use JSModel.cities. And about the intellisense; it won't appear because these variables are of C# which is server side not at your JS level so JS intellisense won't recognize them at the time of writing the code. But you can easily use them. To understand about JS objects go thought this link https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp

Comment: @ZakiMohammed, worked, thank you. Was writing Name instead of name...:)